# How do I create a moving average VBA that sweeps through a set of parameters in steps of 5,10,15?

Tags: excel, vba, average, trading

This code is to create a positioning tool for trading in financial markets.

I would greatly appreciate help.

```
Sub Mov_Avgs()

'last row
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'last colummn
Dim LastCol As Integer
LastCol = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow), _
        ActiveSheet.Range("**E6**"), **5**, False, False, False          

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I am placing the output at an offset from the input data, you can amend as appropriate. Also assumed data in in Sheet(1) and have fully qualified references:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Mov_Avgs()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim step As Long
    Dim outputRange As Range
    Dim stepArr()
    Dim i As Long

    Dim inputRange As Range
    stepArr = Array(5, 10, 15)

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    Lastrow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = ws.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set inputRange = ws.Range("$C$6:$C" & Lastrow)

    For i = LBound(stepArr) To UBound(stepArr)

        Set outputRange = inputRange.Offset(0, LastCol + i)

        Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", inputRange, _
                        outputRange, stepArr(i), False, False, False

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah cool man. Hmmmm.... Seems to tell me the input range contains non-numeric data - weird....

Comment: If referring to the NA() in the output; these are for periods excluded from the calculation as not enough data points to perform the calculation e.g. if 5 point average then first 4 rows of output will be NA().

Comment: No I get a popup message stating that - the N/A in the output is something Im already familiar with.

Comment: Check your input range then i'm guessing.

Comment: Hmm yh I think you are right but Im almost 100% sure that I have the correct inputrange. Sorry if Im being stupid.

Comment: Loop the inputrange and test with isnumeric and debug.print Cell.address where False ? i.e.  For i = 6 To Lastrow
     If IsNumeric(ws.Cells(i, "C")) Then
     Else: Debug.Print ws.Cells(i, "C").Address
  
   End If
   Next i   .Extended conversations on here will be moved to chat btw.

Comment: I dont think I even have chat - only just joined this community.

Comment: I don't know how to move this to chat so i hope someone else might assist. Did you try the code in the comment above to see if you had non numeric data in your source range? You can also do debug.print inputRange.address to confirm the range of data being used for the calculation which will be printed to the immediate window (ctrl + G).